# A strange operator on my new calculator

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Yesterday, I bought a new calculator in an antique shop. I wanted to try some basic operations to see if it was working well. Everything felt right, except for the + sign: it seemed like it was replaced with an obscure new operator!

At first, I tried these additions that seemed totally fine:

```
5 + 5 = 10
6 + 5 = 11
39 + 8 = 47
6 + 3 + 7 + 10 = 26
```

But then, things started to go slightly off with some additional tries:

```
6 + 4 = 12
7 + 3 + 10 = 21
8 + 4 + 9 = 22
```

So I computed more operations, and nothing made sense anymore!

```
2 + 2 = 10
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 1
5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 130
3000 + 333 + 30 + 3 = 1020
```

My last hope to try to understand this operator was to compute a random big number to understand what's going on, but all I got was:

```
17603415 + 33 = ERROR
```

So, can you tell me **what is this operator that replaced the + sign on my calculator?**

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think the operation replacing + is

> "represented in base"
>  That is, "a + b" is "a" (in base 10) represented in base "b".

Examples

> 6 + 5 = (1 x 5) + 1 = 11
>  6 + 3 + 7 + 10 = ((6 + 3) + 7) + 10 = (20 + 7) + 10 = 26 + 10 = 26
>  8 + 4 + 9 = (8 + 4) + 9 = 20 + 9 = 22
>  1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 1 + 3 + 4 = 1 + 4 = 1
>  5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 10 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 20 + 5 + 5 = 40 + 5 = 130
>  3000 + 333 + 30 + 3 = 93 + 30 + 3 = 33 + 3 = 1020

Finally the last result produces an error because

> We would need to use additional characters beyond the regular digits to represent it.

In fact

> If we use letters of the alphabet to represent additional digits, a=10, b=11,... then the result would be "error"

Comment: Quick solve! rot13(V rqvgrq gur ynfg pnyphyngvba jvgu gur pbeerpg onfr bs 33 naq abg 30, tvivat n zhpu zber fngvfslvat rkcynangvba sbe gur REEBE erfhyg!)

Comment: OHH! That last "In Fact" is the kicker! Beautiful! Good solve, @hexomino, and nice puzzle, @Jujustum!